# How to merge array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to Merge two arrays in a array using javascript but i'm not getting the exact output using *concat* method ,can any one help me

```
  var v1 = [[0, 1],[1, 5],[2,5]];
  var v2 = [[0,5],[1,6],[2,8]];
//output
  var result=[[0,1,5],[1,5,6],[2,5,8]];
```

Comment: Can you provide minimal working example. Anything you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat the array and filter the duplicates from array. This is assume that v1 and v2 will be of same length.

```js
var v1 = [[0, 1],[1, 5],[2,5]];
var v2 = [[0,5],[1,6],[2,8]];
let result = []

for (let i = 0 ; i < v1.length; i++) {
  let d = v1[i].concat(v2[i])
  result.push(d.filter((a, b) => d.indexOf(a) === b))
}
console.log(result)
//var result=[[0,1,5],[1,5,6],[2,5,8]];
```

Simply Something Like this , Haven't actually compiled it but this is the idea.

```
    let length = (v1.length > v2.length) ? v1.length : v2.length; 
    for (let i = 0 ; i < length; i++) {

          if (v2[i] && v1[i]) {
            let d = v1[i].concat(v2[i])
            result.push(d.filter((a, b) => d.indexOf(a) === b))
          } else {
            if (v1.length > v2.length) {
      result.push(v1[i].filter((a, b) => v1[i].indexOf(a) === b)); //remove v1 dup 
} else {
  result.push(v2[i].filter((a, b) => v2[i].indexOf(a) === b)); //remove v2 dup 
}

          }

        }
        console.log(result)
```

Comment: what if size are unequal?

Comment: then check the size of both array. The greater size will be evaluated . Suppose v1 is greater the check if v2[i] exists. If not then simply append v1[i] in new array.

Answer (score 2):

Use `map()` on one of them. Join it with other using the corresponding index. Then du remove the duplicates using `Set`

```js
  var v1 = [[0, 1],[1, 5],[2,5]];
  var v2 = [[0,5],[1,6],[2,8]];

const res = v1.map((x, i) => [...new Set([...x, ...v2[i]])]);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe  this is more simpler and easier to read:

```
let a = [[0, 1],[1, 5],[2,5]];
let b = [[0,5],[1,6],[2,8]];

b.forEach(item => a.push(item));

// Result :
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); // a = [[0,1],[1,5],[2,5],[0,5],[1,6],[2,8]]
```